# Using Angular.js $resource of $http.get to display results from json API

Tags: json, angularjs, api

I'm trying to switch from sourcing my json locally to fetching it with an API. I've had it working locally, but can't seem to access it when requesting it using the API. My formatting must be incorrect, but I'm not sure what I'm searching for that's incorrect.

This is the way that I've been getting the json from my local directory before moving to the API:

```
countClocks.factory('thisClock', ['$resource',
 function($resource){
 return $resource('clocks/:clockId.json', {}, {
 query: {method:'GET', params:{clockId:'clock'}, isArray:true}
 });
}]);
```

My current json cones from a file called clocks.json and looks like this:

```
{
"id": "ch-1",
"slug": 1,
"title": "Ch 1 Name", 
"content": "Some text about orange clocks"
}
```

I've tried switching the resource url and parameters, but haven't had any luck. Here's the format that I changed it to:

```
countClocks.factory('thisClock', ['$resource',
 function($resource){
 return $resource('http://www.example.org/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=clocks', {}, {
 query: {method:'GET', params:{clockId:'clock'}, isArray:true}
 });
}]);
```

And this is what my new json looks like:

```
{
 "status":"ok",
 "count":10,
 "count_total":12,
 "pages":2,
 "posts":[
    {
     "id":51,
     "slug":"chapter1",
     "url":"http:\/\/www.orangeclocks.com\/chapter1\/",
     "title":"Chapter 1",
     "content":"<p>It would be great to live here.<img class=\"alignleft\" alt=\"\" src=\"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/600\/400\/nature\/3\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"400\" \/><\/p>\n",
     "excerpt":"<p>It would be great to live here.<\/p>\n",
     },
     {
     "id":49,
     "slug":"chapter2”,
     "url":"http:\/\/www.orangeclocks.com\/chapter2\/",
     "title":"Chapter 2”,
     "content":"<p>&nbsp;<\/p>\n<p>Big Little.<br \/>\n<img class=\"alignleft\" alt=\"\" src=\"http:\/\/lorempixel.com\/600\/400\/nature\/2\/\" width=\"600\" height=\"400\" \/><\/p>\n",
      }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the absolute url `http://www.example.org/api/get_tag_posts/?tag_slug=clocks`

1) If `example.org` is on a different domain than your application, you are likely running into cross-domain request issues. You aren't allowed to make cross-domain requests unless the domain allows it in the response headers for that resource.

2) You defined the url parameter `clockId` in your query action, but the url you are using doesn't include it. If it's just a static url you need, then remove the parameter.

Do a little debugging in the browser. If you are getting a valid response from the server, look at the JSON in the reponse and make sure it matches what you are expecting. Also look for any console errors.

Comment: I'm getting a 200 response, though, which leads me to believe that I'm able to access the data from that url. That said, I still don't understand what type of parameter I should be using in that case.

Comment: You don't need a parameter if you just need to use a static url with no variables. If you are getting a 200 response, look at what json is returned in the response to make sure it matches what you are expecting. It needs to be in the same format as your json file was in.

Comment: No, no errors, but I looked through everything I could and found that the a message stating that the URL only accepts POST, so that's something.

Comment: If it only accepts POST, then why did it not return an error?

Comment: Your problem is not with your client-side code. You have verified that works. The problem here is with the server api you are using, or the url. Rather than concentrate on testing your app, you should just be typing the url into your browser and trying to get the expected JSON to show up.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't get an error. If I visit my url, I can see my json. Despite what firebug is telling me, I think that I'm having cross domain issues.

Comment: If you see your JSON when you visit the url, the only things I can think of besides cross domain issues is that maybe the server is not returning content type `application/json` or the JSON is not in the correct format